# Hierarchical message/reply in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a message/reply application. The idea is to have a message displayed and any replies are displayed directly below it in hidden divs with the text "show message from ...".

I don't have any problem with the layout itself and have that working fine, but what I am unsure of, is how to return a single message with multiple replies. The SQL query below is what I have to date, but this will return all the replies, but also repeats the main message for each reply.

My question is, how can I return the main message once, and the all the associated replies?

```
SELECT u.userid, u.first, u.last, c.title, c.body, c.messid, 
   c.adddate, ru.first, ru.last, cr.body, cr.messreplyid 
FROM chat c INNER JOIN users u on u.userid = c.userid 
 LEFT JOIN chat_reply cr on cr.messid = c.messid 
 LEFT JOIN users ru on ru.userid = cr.userid 
WHERE c.messid =".$_GET['messid']." 
GROUP BY cr.messreplyid"


u.userid = the original posters primary key
u.first + u.last = the original posters name
c.title = the title of the post
c.body = the message body
c.messid = the message primary key
c.adddate = message timestamp
ru.first + ru.last = the name of the person who replied
cr.body = the the reply message body
cr.messreplyid = the reply primary key
```

As I said, I seem to get two results, one will show a single message with a single reply(if I don't use the group by) or all the replies but repeats the message. I'm sure this can be done with a complex query, such as a select within a select, but would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Why not make two separate SQL calls?

Comment: @mellamokbtheWise I revisited the code based on your suggestion of two calls and managed to get it to work. I looped through the first record set, then add the second loop within the first. And it worked t way I wanted it to. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

The child posts need to reference their parent posts with something else than the primary key. What you are doing in the JOIN won't work because the primary key is always different.

For example, if the `messreplyid` of the children contained the `messid` of the parent, you could do `LEFT JOIN chat_reply cr on cr.messreplyid = c.messid`

Don't do grouping or you'll get only one reply.

And please, for the love of god, don't use an unsanitized `$_GET` variable when putting together an SQL statement! You'll open yourself up to SQL injections!

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have wrapped the $_GET variable in a mysql_real_escape_string. 

I already have the join between parent and child as you mentioned. LEFT JOIN chat_reply cr on cr.messid = c.messid. messid is the foreign key in the chat_reply table that corresponds to the primary key messid in the parent table. 

But what I get from that for example is, if I have three replies, I get three same separate parent messages each with a reply attached, instead of one parent message with three replies attached.

Comment: You'll always get the parent message multiple times if you are using `JOIN`. If you want separate data, you'll have to do two SQL queries, one for the parent message and one for the child messages, using the `messid` from the parent message in a `WHERE` clause.